# How can I get the machine name of a server from its IP address?

Tags: iphone, ios, ip-address

Can anyone tell me how to get the machine name where the server is hosted
i know its IP address.
I know it can be sent from the server itself but still was curious about how it could be done from the Iphone.
Thnks in advance
Regards
Nitesh

Comment: "get machine of the server" i dont understand!

Comment: ok machine name like..??

Comment: I just hope the name of the machine won't be `T-800` or `T-1000` either...

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're trying to do a reverse DNS lookup. There are some web-based services which you could use from an iPhone. For example: http://www.ipchecking.com/

However, if the IP address is being used by more than one server, this may not give you helpful results. It's also possible that the service you're looking for on the server could respond only to a name different than the one listed.